# Debug Angular2 routing

Tags: angular2-routing

I have two routes. Each points to the lazy loaded module's empty route.

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: 'files', loadChildren: './company/company.module#CompanyModule'},
    {path: 'lookup', loadChildren: './lookup/lookup.module#LookupModule'}
];
```

The module's routes look like this:

```
export const companyRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ClientFilesComponent}
];

export const companyRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(companyRoutes);
```

---

```
export const lookupRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: LookupListComponent}
];

export const lookupRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forChild(lookupRoutes);
```

First works, second doesn't. I can see that the Lookup module is loading, but the LookupListComponent never gets created. No errors or messages.

If I add another level to the Lookup routing it starts working

```
{ path: 'list', component: LookupListComponent}
```

Now /lookup/list works. But /lookup doesn't.

I don't like the idea that the word 'lookup' is the problem here. What else could it be?

Thank you.

Comment: _First works, second doesn't._ what happens when you navigate to `/lookup`?

Comment: @Maximus, as I said - the module loads, but the component is not created. So from the UI standpoint nothing happens, just some delay while module is loading.

Comment: have you added `LookupListComponent` to `entryComponents`?

Comment: What is entryComponents? The configuration seems to be exactly the same for me, but one works, other doesn't. I actually have more routes like this and 'Lookup' is the only one failing.

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `companyRoutes` & `lookupRoutes` as below:

**companyRoutes**

```
export const companyRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            path: '',
            component: ClientFilesComponent
        ]
    }
];
```

**lookupRoutes**

```
export const lookupRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
            path: '',
            component: LookupListComponent
        ]
    }
];
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: That doesn't change anything

Comment: How are you routing/switching between the paths?

Comment: I tried routerLink and also just typing direct url in the browser bar. Same results.